# how to open a android application by telegram bot api inline keyboard php

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-api

I want to make the user select a inline button in the Telegram bot to run and open an application installed on the device (if it is installed and available).
For example, what can I put in the value of the address in the following code?

```
$keyboard =
   [
           'inline_keyboard' =>
            [
              [
               ['text' => 'open my application', 'url' => '']   
              ]
           ]
   ];
```

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Please share more details. How is this problem related to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

##### No, this is not possible.

---

From the [InlineKeyboard Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) page:

> ##### `url`
>
> `HTTP` or `tg://` URL to be opened when the button is pressed.
> Links `tg://user?id=<user_id>` can be used to mention a user by their ID without using a username, if this is allowed by their privacy settings.

So since there is no way to pass a 'custom' url like `mailto:`, there is no way to open an other app installed on the phone.